How to assess the goodness-of-fit of an extended Cox model?
I'm trying to build an extended Cox hazard model on a dataset with time-varying covariates, using Python's Lifeline package. However, I've a hard time trying to find out how I can assess the goodness-of-fit of my data.
With non-time-varying covariates, I understand that the Harrell's Concordance Index or the AUC could be used. However, given how the c-index work, I don't see how it can make sense on a long format data, where each record indicates a state change.



ID
Start Time
End Time
Variable 1
Event




ABC
1
5
500
No


ABC
5
15
250
No


ABC
15
23
350
Yes


DEF
1
4
250
No


DEF
4
12
410
No



I understand that one is not supposed to use the extended Cox model to perform prediction on the future with time-varying variables. Nonetheless, surely there should still be a way to assess how well the model is performing on existing past data (i.e. the training or test data)? Otherwise, how else am I supposed to tune the hyperparameters of the model?

This page and its links might provide some guidance.
